# priority between numeric_detection and dynamic_templates

Tags: elasticsearch

There are priorities based on the sequence in the `dynamic_templates` but is there any between `numeric_detection` and the `dynamic_templates`?

> [Templates are processed in order — the first matching template wins.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#dynamic-templates)

Is it safe to say that `dynamic_templates` has lower (or higher) priority than `numeric_detection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numeric_detection` is not a template. It is `field mapping`. When you specify multiple `templates` then they will be processed in order.

I tried the below exercise to confirm the precedence between `numeric detection` and `dynamic templates`.

**Mapping:**

```
{
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "integers": {
          "match_mapping_type": "long",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "short"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "numeric_detection": true
}
```

If it detects a number, it has two options. One to set as `long` which is said by enabling `numeric_Detection` and another one if it is `long` set it as `short` which is handled by `dynamic_templates`.

Then indexed the below data

```
{
 "whoami":"25"
}
```

Then I checked the mapping. I found this.

```
"properties": {
  "whoami": {
    "type": "short"
  }
}
```

Then, I tried disabling `dynamic field` mapping.

```
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "integers": {
        "match_mapping_type": "long",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "short"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "numeric_detection": false
}
```

This time, `whoami` is stored as `text`.

So the priority is as below.

1. Dynamic field mapping - Highest
2. Dynamic template mapping - Lowest

`dynamic field` identifies what rule has to be applied. Once the rules are applied by `dynamic field mapping` then custom rules are applied by `dynamic template mapping`

Comment: Thanks for the demos, and in this demo it's correct to say the priorities between them. However I have to say it's not sufficient to say "it's safe to think there is a strict rule". As I have some other demos to demonstrate against the rules you have in the answer: saying `numeric_detection` is higher over `dynamic_templates`.

Comment: Yes, I say the same. numeric detection has higher priority than templates @Hearen

Comment: thanks for the so lightning reply, I just enclosed my demos in the second answer to elaborate my confusion. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gibbs. Have a nice day ;)

Comment: Glad, it helped, Happy coding @Hearen

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help of Gibbs, I read the doc for other more times and have more demos tested.

I think it would be safe to say that [`dynamic templates`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#match-unmatch) will take effect once the following conditions specified.

> - the data type detected by Elasticsearch, with match_mapping_type.
> - the name of the field, with match and unmatch or match_pattern.
> - the full dotted path to the field, with path_match and path_unmatch.

While the first condition confused me (which Gibbs helped to clear out that confusion), the "data type" should be the *type* after `field mapping`.

As for the field mapping rules, we could check the details at [dynamic field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html).

> - string
>
> > Either a date field (if the value passes date detection), a double or long field (if the value passes numeric detection) or a text field, with a keyword sub-field.

---

The demo will give us a `keyword` for `uid` using `match` to specify the dynamic template:

```
GET my_index/_mapping

PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "numeric_detection": true,
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings_as_keywords": {
          "match": "uid",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

POST my_index/_doc/1
{
  "uid": "123"
}
```

Comment: That's same. First numeric detection converts "123" to long "123". And dynamic templates mapping matches "123" because you have `*`. Then it keeps that as keyword as you have convert rule as keyword. How is it different? I said that both will be executed in order. @Hearen

Comment: You are saying that the type detection goes first and then the dynamic templates go after? Is that correct? Sorry to ask this: do you have some official resources or source code snippets? I am so afraid to have a wrong assumption to cause online bugs ;(

Comment: Indeed, you mentioned: "Once the rules are applied by dynamic field mapping then custom rules are applied by dynamic template mapping". Sorry I missed that.